# accessing session variables in an Rspec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am testing a login api for a mobile site using Rspec (2.13.0) request specs. I have a login_user method which correctly writes a user to test database and generates an auth_token in db.

I don't think that the auth_token is being set correctly as a session value in the example "just testing mobile-login-page". I can see though that the redirect occurs after login and that the correct auth_token is send on that redirect (see comment in login_user method).

Is my syntax incorrect (this is my first time using a request spec for something like this)? Would I be better off using a controller spec or using rack-test?

thx in advance

```
def login_user
  @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  visit '/arc/signin'
  fill_in 'Email', with: 'jxt@jxt.com'
  fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar'
  click_button 'Log in'
  # from test.log showing that auth_token is actually called
  # Processing by UsersController#home as HTML
  # ESC[1mESC[35mUser Load (0.4ms)ESC[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'pCnpG90vIw3qUAoXx3EBsA' LIMIT 1
  #
end

it "just testing the mobile-login-page" do
  login_user
  get '/arc/v1/api/signup-mobile-test'
  puts response.body
  JSON.parse(response.body)[:auth_token] == (@user.auth_token)
end
```

in controller:

```
def create_user_test                                           
  m={}                                                         
  m[:status]="success"                                         
  m[:auth_token]=session[:auth_token]
  render :json => m.to_json                                    
end
```

and here's the output:

```
Fri Apr 26$ rspec spec/requests/static_page_spec.rb 
{"status":"success","auth_token":null}
.....

Finished in 0.80587 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: are you suing devise?

Comment: No, just has_secure_password; I can verify that the user and auth_token are created correctly in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using two different testing harnesses, and they don't share session state.

The `visit`, `fill_in`, and `click_button` methods you're using go through capybara and rack-test: http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#visit-instance_method

The `get` method you're using to make the API request is from Rails' built-in integration tests: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

If you use `visit` instead of `get` in your second example, the session created from `login_user` will be visible.

Note that testing an API directly using capybara is generally not recommended, as capybara is designed to interact with the site through the user interface as an actual user would. I'm assuming that you're testing a rich UI with a JavaScript API behind it.

If that's the case, I'd use a combination of two testing approaches:

- capybara specs which navigate through the user interface and never access the API directly. These specs can use the session generated when logging in.
- controller specs which directly hit the API to quickly test edge cases and conditions. These specs can pass the session directly to the controller or use a mocking framework to stub out authentication.

Comment: thx Joe, that makes sense. Using controller specs to test an api is also consistent with testing on the discourse app.